# Validator and Enricher in Camel java

Tags: java, validation, routes, apache-camel

I am writing a camel route to inject a feed to database. What is the way to inject validators and enrichers class in route.

```
from(jmsDestinationUri)
        .id("DataWriteDBRoute")
        .autoStartup(ifNeededConsumerActive)
        .unmarshal(jsonDataFormatterForPosition)
        .split(myCustomSplitter)
        .validate( . . . )
        .enrich( . . . )
        .process(feedToDBWriter)
        .log("Record successfully written to DB.");
```

Comment: I'm not fully shure what you are asking for. How to write the stuff inside validate or enrich? [validate](http://camel.apache.org/validate.html) expects eiter a `Predicate` or an `Expression` to be passed in, which can either be a simple expression or a header or body or other value. The [enricher](http://camel.apache.org/content-enricher.html) takes a Camel source URI as String and optionally an `AggregationStrategy` as argument, where you can decide what parts of which exchange to take and how to aggragate things into the final exchange passed further on.

Comment: @RomanVottner I have specific classes for both... For example GenericValidator which validates all fields in domain class for validations and few enrichers like DateEnricher which gets date from DB based on some parameter in domain object.

I want to inject these classes in route. What is the best way to do so. As of now I have induced them as process only but that does't looks good.

Comment: Do you use Spring? If so, define them as beans, give them meaningful names and then annotate these fields/setter method or the constructor inside your Route class via either `@Autowired @Qualifier(name="...")` or simply via `@Resource(name="...")`. You of course need to expose the class defining the route as Spring bean as well so that Spring will actually create a Proxy object for it and inject the objects.